# Non top-level opengl widget in tkinter

Tags: python, opengl, tkinter

I have a existing tkinter gui to which I would like to add a openGL widget. However, it appears that the OpenGL widget only works if it is toplevel.

This works:

```
from OpenGL.Tk import *
from Tkinter import *
herp=Opengl(height=100,width=100)
herp.pack()
herp.mainloop()
```

But this does not:

```
from OpenGL.Tk import *
root=Tk()
b=Opengl(root,height=100,width=100)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\sith\user_files\2013-Softerns\new_gui_planning\LearningOpenGL\integration_3.py", line 4, in <module>
    b=Opengl(root,height=100,width=100)
  File "C:\Python27_32bit\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\Tk\__init__.py", line 267, in __init__
    apply(RawOpengl.__init__, (self, master, cnf), kw)
  File "C:\Python27_32bit\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\Tk\__init__.py", line 216, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'togl', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27_32bit\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2036, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: invalid command name "togl"
```

Do I need to import togl?

The only other thing I could find on this is:

http://computer-programming-forum.com/56-python/ece79da9298c54de.htm

But their solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the PyOpengl wrapper for togl is using a default root window.

You should be able to get a reference to it via the master attribute
of your Opengl widget.

```
from Tkinter import *
from OpenGL.Tk import *

b=Opengl(height=100,width=100)
root = b.master
f = Frame(root, width=100, bg='blue')
f.pack(side='left', fill='y')
b.pack(side='right', expand=1, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oblivion, your solution works perfectly! For those in the same situation, if you need to use the opengl widget later on in your code, you can 'extract' the root and then redefine the opengl widget later. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

on linux i install it using those commands , then the example above are worked for me   :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install togl-demos
```